# missing go.sum entry for module providing package <package_name>

Tags: go, go-modules, buffalo

Using the buffalo framework,
after bootstraping it via `buffalo new <project_name>`

I am trying to run `buffalo dev`
Expecting to see:

> project running on port 3000

But I am getting those error messages instead

```
actions/app.go:4:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo (imported by sc_api/actions); to add:go get sc_api/actions

actions/app.go:13:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/gobuffalo/mw-csrf (imported by sc_api/actions); to add: go get sc_api/actions
```

`actions/app.go` has been generated by buffalo, but in case you are wondering the error does match the import statement in this file.

```
// app.go
package actions

import (
    "github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo"  // 1rst line
    "github.com/gobuffalo/envy"
    forcessl "github.com/gobuffalo/mw-forcessl"
    paramlogger "github.com/gobuffalo/mw-paramlogger"
    "github.com/unrolled/secure"

    "sc_api/models"

    "github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo-pop/v2/pop/popmw"
    csrf "github.com/gobuffalo/mw-csrf"  // 2nd line
    i18n "github.com/gobuffalo/mw-i18n"
    "github.com/gobuffalo/packr/v2"
)
```

What does it mean ? How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 380, accepted):

It seems the issue has nothing to do with Buffalo and more with my lack of understanding of Go in general.

running `go mod tidy` solved the issue

This command goes through the `go.mod` file to resolve dependencies:

- delete the packages that are not needed
- download those needed
- update the `go.sum`

I am still unsure which of those actions did the trick... but the project runs now.

ps: I'll let the in-depth explanation/correction to the *Go wizard* out here.

Comment: Total go noob here too, this helped me!

Comment: Cool, faced same issue & it helped :)

Comment: Update dependencies and broke my code, now I can't get it back to its original state

Comment: Thanks this I am new on go, so forget to run this in existing project when get you clone a new projects.

Comment: `go mod tidy -e` worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

i got the same issue when building a docker image. i tried `go mod tidy` and
also `go get -t .` as suggested here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44129. both didnt worked for me though but updating my docker builder to version `1.18` worked.

Comment: I had the same issue while using `FROM golang:1.16-alpine as builder` in dockerfile, upgrading the version to 1.18 solved the issue.

Answer (score 13):

I use `go mod tidy -e` solved the problem. The -e flag (added in Go 1.16) causes go mod tidy to attempt to proceed despite errors encountered while loading packages.The more about `mod tidy`: https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy

Comment: saved xmas and it's not even xmas thank you

Answer (score 1):

`go get -t` did the trick for me.

read up on the difference [here](https://medium.com/@chaewonkong/difference-between-go-get-and-go-install-in-go-a076d7352186)